# Проверка множеств на равенство

Tags: c++, алгоритм, шаблоны-с++, stl, множества

```
set<string> s1;
set<string> s2;
```

Как правильно проверить множества на равенство?

Comment: Сравнить длину. Сравнить попарно элементы. Нет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (s1 == s2)
{
    // Равны
}
else
{
    // Не равны
}
```

См. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp